# Finding a chain with no least or greatest elements for $(\mathcal{P}(\mathbb{N}),\subseteq)$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, order-theory

I have a poset $(\mathcal{P}(\mathbb{N}),\subseteq)$, where $\mathcal{P}$ is a power set, and I need to find a non-empty chain, such as that chain would not have the least or greatest element.

It is easy for me to imagine a chain in $(\mathcal{P}(\mathbb{N}),\subseteq)$, but I can't really grasp the idea of how do I make up a chain with no least element.

From what I have googled so far, I can suppose it should be somehow related to the poset $(\mathbb{Q},\subseteq)$, but I don't know how to develop that idea (in case it shall lead me to an answer at all).

Comment: Hint: can you find such a chain in $(\mathcal P(\mathbb Q),\subseteq)$? Can you turn it into a chain in $(\mathcal P(\mathbb N),\subseteq)$?

Comment: Hint: if you can make a chain with no greatest element, then if you replace each element of the chain with its complement, you get a chain with no least element.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**I.** Define $A_n\in\mathcal P(\mathbb N)$ for $n\in\mathbb Z$ by setting
$$A_n=\{1,3,5,7,\dots\}\setminus\{1,3,5,\dots,2|n|-1\}\text{ for }n\lt0,$$
$$A_n=\{1,3,5,7,\dots\}\cup\{2,4,6,\dots,2n\}\text{ for }n\ge0.$$
Then $m\lt n\implies A_m\subsetneq A_n$.

**II.** Establish a one-to-one correspondence netween $\mathbb N$ and the set $S=\{x+iy:x,y\in\mathbb N\}$. Define a chain in $\mathcal P(S)$ by setting $B_\theta=\{z\in S:0\lt\arg z\lt\theta\}$ for $0\lt\theta\lt\frac\pi2$.
Then $\phi\lt\theta\implies B_\phi\subsetneq B_\theta$.